# Can't Accsess database in all the activity in my android aplication?

Tags: android, sqlite

Am developing one apps using sqlite.I created database in main Activity ,I created that database in the "**MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE**" mode.I can only access this database within alone that activity only,but i need to use same database for all activity.What can i do for single  database for all the activity accessible  within that application.I don't know how to proceed that . this is my first apps using sqlite,So anyone help me to fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create `SQLiteOpenHelper` using `activity.getApplicationContext()`.

Now you open the database using the activity context, so it is available only for your activity. If you open your db using application context, it will be reachable from any activity of your application.